# SCSS Support in Aptana 3.0.4 Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, sass

Is there a full scss support in the apatana eclipse plugin 3.0.4?
The editor assigns the sass-editor, but there seems to be no coloring available. source format also don't make anything.

Comment: Good info on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632150/aptana-studio-3-code-assist-for-sass-scss-files

Answer (score 1):

The basic SCSS support - syntax coloring, folding - is there in 3.0.4; if you see any issues around those areas, please file a ticket at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD.  Formatting and outline are not available yet.  You could also add feature request for each specific feature at JIRA.

Hope this helps.