# JetBrains IDE with Demandware

Tags: e-commerce, demandware

I was wondering if anyone has used Demandware with any of JetBrains IDE. I've always just used text editors, and the Terminal. It seems like Demandware UX Studio is only for Eclipse?

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In theory you can use your editor of choice to edit Demandware ISML files and DW Script files such as Sublime or JetBrains, but you would need some kind of WebDAV-Sync solution to automatically upload your files to the server.

You'll also lose debugging when you move away from Eclipse. Editing pipelines will also be quite challenging, as you won't have the visual IDE to edit the files (which are basically just XML).

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately there has been some movement in the community and a plugin has been created for Jetbrains, it is available here: https://github.com/nek4life/intellij-demandware/

Answer (score 3):

There is a Sublime Text 3 plugin (officially supported by Demandware) that will handle webdav syncing with your sandbox server. Pipelines are going away with the new development model and script debugging from Sublime Text is listed as a current TODO. You will still need to return to Eclipse to debug until that feature is finished, but it's nice to see they are making progress.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Entropy

Answer (score 1):

Till now, Demandware development extension is available only for eclipse IDE. After installing the demandware development extension, you can take code checkout the storefront cartridges and create the DW server connection in eclipse, which will help you auto upload files to server.

You can use any other IDE, but that will not help you auto sync/auto upload files on server and with pipeline debugging options.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Aptana studio. It is compatible with DW studio plugin.

To use Aptana:

1. Install Aptana
2. Go to Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software
3. Add luna location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/
4. Enable "Eclipse Kepler Update Site"
5. Install dw studio as described in documentation (use version for luna)

Optionally configure scss default editor: [Aptana Studio 3 code assist for Sass (.scss) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632150/aptana-studio-3-code-assist-for-sass-scss-files)